# Caller Contextual Binding NInject

Tags: ninject

I need to compose an instance conditionally depending on the caller.

In some cases I need a composite object instances with a "deep" type "NullService"

in other cases I instead inject a "ConcreteService"

I expect something like this:

```
Get<Root>.with(NullService)
```

or

```
 Get<Root>.with(ConcreteService)
```

or better still if one could bind the construction so that it dated back to the calling context

```
Bind<IService>.to(ConcreteService).
Bind<IService>.to(NullService).only.whenCallerIsTypeOf(CallerWhosNeedsANullService)
```

is it possible?

Comment: What kind of condition do you have? Config value, Runtime Condition, User Input, ...

Comment: Runtime Condition.

In particular in a ASP.net application as a function of the page called.

For this reason I wrote:
`Bind<IService>.to(NullService).only.whenCallerIsTypeOf(CallerWhoseNeedsANullService)`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1. Use an own condition in case you can calculate which one should be used:

   ```
   Bind<IService>.To(NullService)
       .When(ctx => IsCallerWhosNeedsANullService(HttpContext.Current.Request));
   ```
2. Use Named bindings

   ```
   Bind<Root>().ToSelf().Named("DefaultRoot");
   Bind<Root>().ToSelf().Named("NullRoot");
   Bind<IService>.To(ConcreteService);
   Bind<IService>.To(NullService).WhenAnyAnchestorNamed("NullRoot");

   Get<Root>("NullRoot");
   ```